# How to create a generic Map

Tags: haskell

I can create a simple Map from `Int` to `[Bool]` like this

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

simpleMap :: Map Int [Bool]
simpleMap = 
  Map.insert 1 [True, False] .
  Map.insert 1 [False, True] $ Map.empty
```

the compiler than tells me that the type of this map is

```
simpleMap :: Map Int [Bool]
```

and this is all very good.

Now, I want to create a more generic Map from `Just a` to `[a]`, if I write something like

```
genericMap :: Map (Maybe a) [a]

genericMap = 
  Map.insert (Just True) [True, False] .
  Map.insert (Just False) [False, True] $ Map.empty
```

I get the following compile error

> ```
> * Couldn't match type `a' with `Bool'
>   `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
>     the type signature for:
>       genericMap :: forall a. Map (Maybe a) [a]
>     at test.hs:23:1-31
>   Expected type: Map (Maybe a) [a]
>     Actual type: Map (Maybe Bool) [Bool]
> ```

However, something like this compiles fine

```
genericMap2 :: (Ord a, Num a) => Map (Maybe a) [a]

genericMap2 = 
  Map.insert (Just 1) [1, 2] .
  Map.insert (Just 2) [3, 4] $ Map.empty
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

**Update**

The whole point of this was just a learning exercise. Ideally I'd like to create a `HigherMap` data type that looks like this (in pseudo code):

```
{
  Just 1 -> [1, 2, 3],
  Just True -> [True, False],
  Just "abc" -> ["def", "ghi"]
}
```

where both the key and the value come from type constructors, and I capture the information that both type arguments are the same.

Comment: Doing what you ask requires rather more machinery than you might guess at first. See [dependent-map](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dependent-map-0.2.4.0/docs/Data-Dependent-Map.html) for a complete, worked example. It is definitely not something you'd want to embark on as a beginner still trying to learn the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A type like `Map (Maybe a) [a]` means whoever uses this variable gets to decide what type to use for `a`. That doesn't work with your `genericMap` definition because it tries to put `Bool` values in there, and I might want to use it at some other type.

`genericMap2` is OK because it uses polymorphic constants: `1 :: (Num a) => a`, so it can be used at any (numeric) type, unlike `True :: Bool`, which has a fixed type.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So how would I go about creating a map which accepts a `Maybe` of any type for its keys?

Comment: @bugs What's your use case? I.e. if you had such a thing, what would you use it for?

Comment: @bugs You are essentially asking for an untyped map (or at least partially untyped). In Haskell, we like to avoid such things as much as possible (even if we might achieve something similar with `Dynamic`).

Comment: @melpomene to be honest, it was just a learning exercise. I'll update the question with more details